# How to get the color of a particle with Python?

Tags: python, particles

I'm trying, with python, to get the color of a given particle in a simple particle system. So far, when I create a particle system, the particle get the color from where it's emitted, right? I can ask for it's position, orientation, and a lot of cool stuff.  But, do you know any way to get the color information? An average RGB will be great.

I guess one way could be through the UV of the emitter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there is no simple way to get the color of a particle. In the case you have an object with UV's and 1 image texture defining the color you should be able to get the color.

The following example is for BI and assumes you only have 1 UV map, the texture is in slot 1 and there is only 1 particle system and 1 modifier (the modifier for the particle system) on the object.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Color

def get_pixel_color(img, x, y):
    # Get the 'index' of the pixel. Pixels are stored as one big list of
    # numbers. The R, G, B and A value for every pixel, one after the other.
    pixel_i = y * img.size[0] * 4 + x * 4
    pixel_col = img.pixels[pixel_i:pixel_i + 4]
    # Return the color as Color object, which doesn't have alpha info.
    return Color((pixel_col[:-1]))

def get_uv_color(img, uv):
    # Get the x and y coordinates of the pixel for the given uv coordinate.
    pixel_x = int(uv.x * img.size[0])
    pixel_y = int(uv.y * img.size[1])
    uv_col = get_pixel_color(img, pixel_x, pixel_y)
    return uv_col

def get_particle_color(p, ps, ps_mod):
    p_uv = ps.uv_on_emitter(ps_mod, p)
    p_mat = bpy.data.materials[ps.settings.material_slot]
    p_mat_tex = p_mat.texture_slots[0].texture
    p_mat_img = p_mat_tex.image
    p_col = get_uv_color(p_mat_img, p_uv)
    return p_col

obj = bpy.context.object       # The object with the particle system
ps = obj.particle_systems[0]   # The particle system you need to query
ps_mod = obj.modifiers[0]      # The modifier for the particle system
p = ps.particles[0]            # The first particle

p_col = get_particle_color(p, ps, ps_mod)
```

For Cycles (assuming that there is only 1 Image Texture node in the Shading Node Tree) you should change the `get_particle_color` function. The statement for `p_mat_tex` should be changed to:

```
p_mat_tex = p_mat.node_tree.nodes['Image Texture']
```

Comment: It works great in my early tests ! Thanks Jasper ! :D

Answer (score -1):

If you using Blender Render

- Particle Halos allows to can set a material on the emitter and select it.  Particles textures can modify color and size among other properties.
- Object and Group Particles maintain their own color

[image]

If you are using Cycles Render

- The [particles info] in the materials node editor can provide more info and can be programmed with the nodes for precisely colored particles.
- Textures can change size and other properties

[image]

Comment: The question specifically asks for a way of getting the colour via python not how to colour the particles themselves.

Comment: These "worse-than-Word-art" arrows are dreadful, you are atomising the reader's sight at the expense of clarity.